# Inserting node at specified index in Linked Lists

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, linked-list

I'm writing the code for Linked Lists and I'm confused when I want to insert a new node at the specified position. I'm wondering why we decrease the position by 1? Here is the code:

```
def insert(self, data, index):
        """
        Inserts a new Node containing data at index position
        Insertion takes O(1) time but finding the node at the 
        insertion point takes O(n) time. 
        """
        if index == 0:
            self.add(data)
        
        if index > 0:
            new = Node(data)
            
            position = index
            current = self.head
            current.next_node
            
            while position > 1:
                current = new.next_node
                position -= 1
                
            prev_node = current
            next_node = current.next_node
            
            prev_node.next_node = new
            new.next_node = next_node
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason you do it is that you try to move the `current` forward `index` elements.
*How* you do that does not matter, whether you decrease the position by one, do a different loop or do something entirely different - as long as you do `current = new.next_node` `index` times.

And that is exactly what

```
while position > 1:
    current = new.next_node
    position -= 1
```

does. It runs that statement `index` times since `position = index` to begin with. An alternative would be

```
for _ in range(index):
    current = new.next_node
```

Note that it most likely should be `current = current.next_node`, not `current = new.next_node`, since `new` never gets updated.